# Powershell Replace Multiline

Tags: regex, powershell

In Powershell I'm trying to replace the following:

```
<Name>RANDOMTEXT</Name>
</Member>
```

With

```
<Name>RANDOMTEXT</Name></Member>
```

I'm using the following code:

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(<XMLFILE>).Replace("</Name>`n</Member>","</Name></Member>")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText(<NEWFILE>, $content)
```

The replace is not working.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try `.Replace("</Name>\`r\`n</Member>","</Name></Member>")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using RegEx replace (the `-replace` operator) as opposed to the static string (method) version, if you want to be able to handle both Windows and Unix style newlines.

Windows style is carriage return followed by linefeed (2 characters, `CRLF` or `` "`r`n" ``), Unix style is just linefeed (`LF` or `` "`n" ``)

Using regex replace:

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(<XMLFILE>) -replace '</Name>\r?\n</Member>','</Name></Member>'
```

Or replacing all newlines:

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(<XMLFILE>) -replace '\r?\n'
```

The question mark `?` makes the `CR` optional (match 0 or 1), so this will encompass all newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.Replace("</Name>" + [Environment]::NewLine + "</Member>","</Name></Member>")`

or `` .Replace("</Name>`r`n</Member>","</Name></Member>") ``

On a General note, if all you want to do is to remove the new lines, you can simply try `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(<XMLFILE>).Replace([Environment]::NewLine,"")`